# A function that integrates to zero against a sequence of weights

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Fix any $a\in(0,1)$.
Is there a nontrivial continuous function $f:[a,1]\to\mathbb R$ so that
$$
\int_a^1t^{-2n}f(t)dt=0
$$
for all integers $n\geq0$ and $f(a)=f(1)=0$?
I would prefer explicit examples, but a proof of existence (or nonexistence) would also be good.

I have a faint feeling that such a function should exist, but I haven't been able to verify it.
It might help to decompose $f$ as a series in a suitable basis, but I haven't encountered a suitable one.
Another possibility that occurred to me is to start with a function that works for $n=0$ (like $f(t)=\sin(2\pi(t-a)/(1-a))$) and recursively modify it to fit all $n$ and to show that the construction converges somewhere, but this method seems unlikely to produce a concrete function.

If it helps to lower the regularity assumption from continuity, feel free to do so.
(I had trouble finding descriptive tags. Suggestions are welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypotheses imply that $\int_a^1 f(t)P(1/t^2)\,dt = 0$ for every polynomial $P.$ But by Stone-Weierstrass, such polynomials are dense in $C([a,1]).$ So now take a sequence of these "polynomials" converging to $f$ uniformly on this interval to see $\int_a^1f(t)^2\,dt = 0,$ which implies $f\equiv 0.$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g(u) = \frac12 f(u^{-1/2}) u^{-3/2}$. 
Then for each $n$:
$$
0 = \int_a^1 t^{-2n} f(t) dt
= \int_1^{a^{-2}} u^n g(u) du
$$

so $g = 0$ (a classical application of the Stone Weiertrass theorem) and $f = 0$.